# .net core 2.0 scoping issue with dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In .Net core 1.0 and 1.1 in my Services Collection I had:

```
services.AddDbContext<VisualJobsDbContext>();
...
...
services.AddScoped<IRecruiterRepository, RecruiterRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
```

this seemed to work. Now I've gone to .net core 2.0 this has stopped working:

I've changed the above to :

```
services.AddDbContext<VisualJobsDbContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped); 
... 
... 
services.AddScoped<IRecruiterRepository, RecruiterRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
```

I still receive the following error using swagger:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service
>   FindaJobRepository.Interfaces.IAccountRepository from singleton
>   FindaJobServices.Interfaces.IAccountService

Does anybody have any ideas what else I can do?

Comment: What is the scope of `IAccountService`?

Comment: @CodeNotFound At the moment it is as above. 'services.AddScoped` but then in one of my MVC controllers I also have it declared as a construction injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IAccountService` is a added as singleton and can't depend on a service with a shorter lifetime. `IAccountRepository` is a scoped service.

Probably you have a constructor with something like this:

```
public IAccountService(IAccountRepository accountRepository) {

}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using construction injection. I use this everywhere. If I simply remove adding it to the service i.e remove `services.addScoped....` I then receive an `unable to resolve service for type IAccountRepository`

Comment: Kristoffer, what do I need to do to. I'm using a typical DI Pattern. I have a Data Layer, a Service Layer and an MVC Layer. All my services are where they should be and I simply do construction injection. As mentioned in my question in .Net Core 1.0 and 1.1 this all worked. At 2.0 it's gone quite wrong. I notice in most examples it shows the DBContext being referenced in the MVC controller. Clearly wrong. This is kept well away from the front end level and sits down in my repository layer and the only way to it is through my service layer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how that ever worked, but essentially your issue is that you're trying to inject scoped services into a singleton, which based on the error is your `AccountService`.

Simply, if you need to use scoped services, the classes you inject them into must *also* be scoped. If you need the lifetime to be singleton, then your only option is use the service locator anti-pattern, where you instead inject `IServiceProvider`, and then create a scope around your operations:

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
    // do something with context
}
```

Importantly, *do not* save the instances you retrieve from your scope to ivars, statics, etc. on your singleton class. These will disposed when the scope is disposed.

Comment: If I inject `IServiceProvider` into my controllers constructor I cannot see a `CreateScope` Method.

Comment: Might require a using. However, you should definitely not be doing this actually in a controller. Controllers are scoped, so you're perfectly fine injecting scoped services there.

Comment: I found the issue for this reference and it's no longer complaining about this class/interface. However I'm also using identity server and into the same MVC constructor I'm injecting `RoleManager<identityRole> roleManager` and this is referenced from a base controller. Because it's all handled by identity server I'm not doing any specific lines of code to add this to the service other than as part of the `services.Addidentity.....` and it's now complaining in a similar way